# Dividir arquivo JS em dois módulos. Erro: objeto usado dentro da função exportada é undefined

Tags: javascript

1. No arquivo marcaBolinha.js eu exporto marcaBolinha():

   ```
    let imagens = document.querySelectorAll('.imagem');

    const bolinhas = document.querySelectorAll('.bolinha');

    let bolinha;

    function achaBolinha() {

    if (bolinha != undefined) {
        bolinha.classList.remove('bolinha-mark'); 
    }

    imagens = document.querySelectorAll('.imagem');
    bolinhas.forEach(element => {
        if (imagens[1].src.indexOf(element.id) > -1) {
            bolinha = element;
            return bolinha;

        }
    })
   ```

   }

   ```
    function marcaBolinha() {
        // resetaBolinhas();
        achaBolinha();
        bolinha.classList.add('bolinha-mark');
    }
   ```
2. A variável 'let bolinha' é atribuída pelo retorno de achaBolinha() em marcaBolinha.js, conforme se vê acima.
3. No arquivo slideShow.js eu importo marcaBolinha() from ./marcaBolinha.js
4. Mas ao executar o programa, aparece o erro: "Can not read property classList of undefined", referindo-se à linha de código "*bolinha.classList.add('bolinha-mark')*" dentro de marcaBolinha().
5. Quando coloco os códigos no mesmo arquivo, funciona normalmente.
6. Segue código no GitHub: https://github.com/torezani89/slideshow3

Comment: @Sam `achaBolinha()` não tem valor de retorno,  o `return bolinha` está dentro do callback da função `foreach`. O que, honestamente, nem faz muito sentido.

Comment: @Bruno Torezani, você está criando as 'bolinhas' dinamicamente depois do import, portanto, quando o seguinte trecho `const bolinhas = document.querySelectorAll('.bolinha');` é executado, ele retorna um nodelist vazio; e, portanto, o trecho `bolinha = element;` nunca é executado.  Sugestão: copie este trecho `const bolinhas = document.querySelectorAll('.bolinha');` para dentro da função `achaBolinha()` do mesmo modo que você fez com imagens.

Comment: Deu certo Vander. Mudei o const bolinhas para let bolinhas e declarei ele novamente dentro de achaBolinha, exatamente como fiz com let imagens. Não precisou mudar o return bolinha de lugar dentro do achaBolinha(). Só com isso já funcionou. Muito grato!